# why this recursive function returns a tuple?

Tags: python, recursion, types

i wrote a simple recursive script to change decimal to hexadecimal, but it returns the answer in tuple, its not a big deal, i get what i want, but i would like to understand why i get a tuple, anyone could explain it?

this is the script:

```
def printDigits(n,base):
    if n < base:
        return n 
    else:
        return printDigits(n//base, base) , n % base
```

and for

```
print(printDigits(245, 16))
```

i get

```
(15, 5)
```

Comment: Recause the return value has a comma.

Comment: You are returning a tuple with `return a, b`.

Comment: You can use `return [n]` and `return [*printDigits(n//base, base), n % base]` to get the converted digits in a one-dimensional list.

Comment: @b-remmelzwaal i didn't know its possible to return a function's result directly into the list, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return in the else statement of printDigits contains a comma, which is how you define a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) in Python.

```
return printDigits(n//base, base) , n % base
```

Answer (score 0):

You went wrong when you decided to return a tuple in the `else` block...

In detail, when the function is called for the first time it goes to the `else` block that returns a TUPLE, and the first element is calling the function again, which returns a integer to the original return statement, and the original return statement returns a tuple!

Yep its a little confusing, try debugging it yourself in vscode.